# Proper way to put the twig files in Symfony Framework

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to symfony3 and so, please bear with me.

From the documentation and most of the tutorials I've encountered, twigs are to be put inside the `app\Resources` directory. Yes, I followed it.

Recently, I discovered this command on creating of a Controller, which is the fastest way I could:

> php bin/console generate:controller --actions=showAction()/profile/:AppBundle:Profile:profile.html.twig`

When executing the above line, it automatically creates `Profile` Controller inside the `src\AppBundle\Controller` and twigs inside the `src\AppBundle\Resources`, note: `Resources` is a new folder created automatically.

Here is the directory:

[image]

From this point, I became curious what really the appropriate folder to store the twig files is. Should I copy and files back to `app` folder?  Are there any reasons behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but if you want, in bestPractices (https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/templates.html#template-locations), they says:

> Store all your application's templates in app/Resources/views/ directory.

Comment: If both are correct and one is best then one practice is inappropriate.. Also, if both are correct, then will only provide confusion to developers (for me). There must be something why these twigs are  automatically stored inside the `src`.

Comment: If you prefer it works in both. If you just use AppBundle, it's recommended to put it in app/ressources/views, because you don't create other Bundles. But, if you prefer use Bundle like src/AdminBundle, src/MyBundle, etc... Then, you put it in src/xxxBundle/Ressources/views. I recommand you to read the link, they explains it better than me.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the other answers are not giving you the full picture, so let's start with a little context.

There was an [issue created on the SensioGeneratorBundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/339) to update the Controller generator to use best practices, but it was closed and marked as a [duplicate of another issue](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/344) that updated the Doctrine CRUD generator. In there, the issue was fixed so that the templates use the `app/Resources/views` directory. I do not feel like the [original issue](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/339) should have been closed.

If you look at the [pull request for the Doctrine CRUD generator](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/pull/377), it changes the bundle directory path from `$bundle->getPath()` to `$this->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.root_dir')`.  However, the Controller generator was never similarly updated.

I believe you have stumbled across something that should be updated within the bundle itself, and that the original issue should have never been closed.  I commented on that issue and might just submit a pull request myself to fix it.

So, to answer your original question, yes you should move them back over to the `app/Resources/views` folder in order to follow Symfony best practices, and eventually the Controller generator command should be updated in the [SensioGeneratorBundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle).

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are fine bcs if you create resources view inside app then it will be accessible in all bundles if you have to create only single bundle then inside bundle resources is also fine. So, Its depends on you. :)

Answer (score 0):

both folder is correct, but Mostly app/Resources use to storage extends twig like layout or email, but inside Controller to use this controller.
But twig from Controller use to antoher controller too

Comment: thanks for the input. But, Is it not  applicable to `src\AppBundle\Resources` ?

Comment: if you had clean Resources App, and use twig only this controller you can put on src\AppBundle\Resources Then you have marked that this twig is used in this controller